# Given generators for a free abelian group, how do we find a basis?

Tags: group-theory

I have a group $G\subset (\mathbb{Z}(s),+)$ which is finitely generated, and since $\mathbb{Z}(s)$ is torision free, so is $G$. Hence $G$ is a f.g. free abelian group.

Now in my problem the generating set is easy to find, but what I'm actually interested in is finding a basis (or even just the rank would already be a start). So my question is if there is some algorithmic way of finding a basis from a generating set?

Comment: There is an algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) if you know the relations of the generators.

Comment: If it was ${\mathbb Z}[s]$ (polynomials) rather than ${\mathbb Z}[s]$ (rational functions), then the Hermite Normal Form algorithm could be used to compute a basis.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes I realise that the fact that these are rational functions makes it a lot more difficult. Actually as a next step I want to consider subgroups $H_r=\{f\in G\mid r\text{ is not a pole of }f\}$, and these subgroups are somehow the essence of the whole story. That's to say: the fact that these are rational functions is essential.

Comment: @DerekHolt Now that you mention it, wouldn't a similar approach still work? Say generators are $\frac{f_1}{g_1},\frac{f_2}{g_2}$, then we want to find $a,b$ such that $af_1g_2+bf_2g_1=0$, where we can group terms by powers in $s$, and apply HNF algorithm to the resulting system?

Comment: Yes I think some form of Hermite Normal Form algorithm is the one to use. Since you are only considering the additive group structure, I think terms with different denominators are effectively linearly independent, so I don't think they really make things more difficult.